# Localisation issue? Number being trimmed at comma when extracting from Textfield

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a Mac app that is trying to get data from a text field.
I populate the text field by taking the 3001 using:

```
mytextfield.integerValue = 3001
```

It then displays the value in the text field of `3,001`. when I extract it using

```
let numberResult = mytextfield.integerValue  //or mytextfield.doublevalue
```

it returns the number `3` ( ie anything after the comma is rounded. )

How do I get the `3001` value back from the textfield correctly?

Here is the examples of the various outputs as requested:

```
print(mytextfield.integerValue) //3
print(mytextfield.intValue) //3
print(mytextfield.doubleValue) //3.0
print(mytextfield.stringValue) //3,001
```

Comment: What Is `Integervalue` (consider that properties and methods are supposed to start with a lowercase letter)?

Comment: Sorry -that was a typo  - have corrected it to integerValue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to convert a user entered string into a number is to use `NumberFormatter`. This will properly handle locale specific grouping and decimal separators.

Methods such as `integerValue` or `doubleValue` do not support localized or formatted values.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy - this makes sense - but feels like an omission/ error on the framework part.  Surely if you assign a value to a textfield - it should return the same value no matter what the localisationin the presentation layer?
Do you have example code?

Comment: Read the documentation for `integerValue`. It clearly states it attempts to convert the string to a number in a non-localized way. In short, this means that no formatting is allowed and there can only be one `.` as the decimal separator.

Comment: link: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1410267-integervalue - seems like a very unexpected way to operate.  Do you have example for the NS Number formatter example

Comment: There are countless examples for using `[NS]NumberFormatter` in Swift. Please do a simple search here to start.